# PostgreSQL update last data inserted field

Tags: postgresql

I try to handle this situation in a PostgreSQL database. I insert data to a table called "Invoice" by programming:

```
invoice_id    account_id    amount  current 
    1            a2322        3      null
    2            a2322       10      null
    3            b4354        1      null
    4            c8099        2      null
    5            a2322        4      null
    6            b4354       -5      null
```

so, when a new record is inserted, I want to update the `current` field with the sum of amounts like this:

```
invoice_id    account_id    amount  current 
    1            a2322        3      null
    2            a2322       10      null
    3            b4354        1      null
    4            c8099        2      null
    5            a2322        4      null
    6            b4354       -5      null
    7            a2322        4      result(sum of amount: 21)
    8            b4354        3      result(sum of amount: -1)
```

Can I do that inside PostgreSQL without programming?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in a trigger `AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE` that runs `FOR EACH STATEMENT`. This is programming too, albeit not on the client side.

In the trigger you can calculate the sums like this (assuming that `invoice_id` is `serial`):

```
INSERT INTO invoice
   (account_id, amount, current)
SELECT account_id, sum(amount), 'result'
FROM invoice
WHERE current IS NULL
GROUP BY account_id
HAVING count(*) > 1
ON CONFLICT (account_id, current)
DO UPDATE
   SET amount = EXCLUDED.amount;
```

This requires a `UNIQUE` constraint on `(account_id, current)` and makes use of the fact that unique constraints allow “duplicate” as long as NULLs are incolved.

Answer (score 0):

This is not technically a direct answer to your question. But what you want is a running number. You *may not* need to store that info. It can be calculated on the fly:

```
SELECT *, SUM(amount) OVER(ORDER BY invoice_id) AS running_total;
```

This way, you won't need to worry about reconciliation and/or update errors. Especially if you later need to update the quantity, the running total will be all messed up, with SUM() OVER(), it will always be consistent.